# Update all Documents - Set Subcollection Order field based on Order within Subcollection

Tags: mongodb

I honestly have no idea how to tag this question, so apologies in advance. If anyone has any tag suggestions I can use to better decorate the question, let me know.

I have a collection of documents that look basically like this (extra fields removed for brevity. for clarity - subcollection is not a hierarchical setup, but rather think something like a one-to-many relationship in a typical database):

```
{
    "_id" : "5d769cefbe793b0f0ce2768b",
    "SubCollection" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5d769ceebe793b0f0ce27627"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5d769ceebe793b0f0ce2761d"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5d769ceebe793b0f0ce2762f"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5d769ceebe793b0f0ce27624"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to update the documents to transform them into something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "5d769cefbe793b0f0ce2768b",
    "SubCollection" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "5d769ceebe793b0f0ce27627",
            "Number" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5d769ceebe793b0f0ce2761d",
            "Number" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5d769ceebe793b0f0ce2762f",
            "Number" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "5d769ceebe793b0f0ce27624",
            "Number" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

I have absolutely no idea how I would write this update query in MongoDB. I know that in SQL Server, I'd just alter the table representing the subcollection and add an auto-incrementing ID field, but as far as I know, that's not possible in MongoDB. The other way I'd do it in SQL Server if I really couldn't use an auto-incrementing field would be to add in the field and then do something like:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT Child.ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Parent.ID) AS rowNum
    FROM Child
    JOIN Parent on Parent.ID = Child.ParentID
)

UPDATE c
SET c.Number = rowNum
FROM Child c
JOIN cte ON cte.ID = Child.ID
```

Does MongoDB have any query method that works similarly?

Comment: What is your mongo version ?

Comment: Srinivasy - 4.0.13

Comment: It would be easy to make this update work with v4.2, Do you need it across all docs or on a particular doc in your collection, Also is there a chance of dumping your version to v4.2 as latest version has better update features dealing with these kind of req's.

Comment: Updating is probably out of the question for right now. Also, it wouldn't be terribly difficult for us to do this through our C# application instead, by simply running updates from a migration process through the MongoDB.NET Driver we're using. So, if there is no relatively "simple" way of doing this through the database itself, we'll just end up using that approach. All that being said, I would like to know how it could be done in v4.2 as well, if that is simpler. Are you suggesting it's not really possible in v4.0?

Comment: yes in that case as far as I know it would be easy to do it thru code. In v4.2 mongo has aggregation pipelines in update longside with $merge which would be helpful to update DB after transformation like this, as in aggregation you could get indexOfArray and merge new field across subdocs on a parent doc..